# gem install gollum on OSX 10.10.3

Tags: osx-yosemite, homebrew

I get this error message when trying to install gollum on Mac OS X 10.10.3 and Macports:

```
sudo gem install charlock_holmes -- --with-icu-dir=/opt/local
```

> ********* icu required (brew install icu4c or apt-get install libicu-dev)

this [question has already been posted](https://superuser.com/questions/751979/os-x-gollum-install-not-working) with the solution being:

> "Follow the error message: use brew to install icu4c".

Is there a way to avoid switching to homebrew to just install one package?

Answer (score 1):

This question is also similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159194/error-installing-charlock-holmes-icu-required), but their answer **also** wound up being "just bail on MacPorts and install Homebrew". I've never been a user of Homebrew — not that there's anything wrong with it, I just started with MacPorts and am fairly set in my ways. So, I dug around a bit more with the first answer instead of the accepted one, and I think I found (part of) your problem: the `--with-icu-dir` should point to `/opt/local/lib/icu` instead of `/opt/local`.

Of course, that's just one piece of the puzzle; the flags you **really** need are `--with-opt-lib` and `--with-opt-include`. That is, `--with-icu-dir` seems to be unnecessary as `gem` appears to be able to find that setting as long as you provide `--with-opt-lib`:

```
sudo gem install charlock_holmes -- --with-opt-lib=/opt/local/lib --with-opt-include=/opt/local/include
```

Though this should be correct, as I use rbenv and [macports from my home directory](https://truongtx.me/2013/11/08/macports-from-home-directory/), my invocation was somewhat different. But the concept remains the same:

```
gem install charlock_holmes -- --with-opt-lib=$HOME/macports/lib --with-opt-include=$HOME/macports/include
```

---

All that being said, my personal target was actually to install with Bundler, so here's some bonus-round material for that:

In order to get Bundler to pass the build flags along appropriately, you can use the `bundle config` command to set the appropriate values, for instance:

```
bundle config --local build.charlock_holmes --with-opt-lib=/opt/local/lib --with-opt-include=/opt/local/include
```

And then a regular `bundle install` should work. Again, for my particular setup though, I had to do it like this:

```
bundle config --local build.charlock_holmes '--with-opt-lib=$HOME/macports/lib --with-opt-include=$HOME/macports/include'
```

The single quotes, while not **strictly** necessary, are cool if I do a bad thing and [check my `.bundle/config` in with the repo](http://bundler.io/rationale.html#checking-your-code-into-version-control), or any other reason I might copy the config to a different user and run it there, as it means the `$HOME` is not evaluated until Bundler's actually building the gem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Mac user, but it looks like your only options are homebrew or install from source. There are instructions on installing from source [here](http://blog.javajosh.com/2010/12/how-to-install-icu-on-osx.html). That post is from 2010, but there are basically identical instructions from 2013 in [this post](http://freddyduarte.com/2013/08/14/installing-the-icu-libraries-and-the-php-intl-extension-on-a-mac/), so they're probably still accurate.

Comment: Thank you for answer Jason (and for editing my question). I followed the instructions, and I get a compilation error : `putil.c:2018:1: error: conflicting types for 'u_versionToString_55'
u_versionToString(UVersionInfo versionArray, char *versionString) {` I cannot post the longer error message in a comment, shall I open a new question?

Comment: If it's not resolved, yes. Open a question specifying the tarball version you installed from, the install command and the error(s) received. However, first, check that you're installing an up-to-date version. I notice the error refers to the file `putil.c`. This file is renamed `putil.cpp` in recent versions, so I think you're installing a 4.x version. Maybe that's the problem. I suspect you used the instructions in the second article I mentioned and followed the link there to the 4.8.1 release. (That would be consistent with the line number at which `u_versionToString` occurs.)

Answer (score 0):

I did install `icu` from MacPorts

```
sudo -E port install icu
```

I then installed `charlock_holmes` using

```
sudo -E gem install charlock_holmes -- \
--with-opt-lib=/opt/local/lib \
--with-opt-include=/opt/local/include/
```

Finally installed Gollum using

```
sudo -E gem install gollum
```

(this is on Mac OS X 10.11.5, fwiw)